# I put the UIView inside a scrollview in my iOS app and it does not scroll. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiscrollview

In my storyboard I put the `UIScrollView` on my `UIViewController`. Inside I put a `UIView` with a `UIButton`, but when I run the app I cannot scroll the `UIView`. What am I doing wrong?

This is how the hierarchy looks:

[image]

and the properties of scroll view:

[image]

and the view (which has a bigger size than scrollview) :

[image]

How can I make it scrollable?

Comment: give your scroll view content size as your biggest view height

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/L44Rdic.png here are my current constraints

Comment: Are you using autolayout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your image it's look like you are using autolayout. So to make view scrollable you need to set the constraints to scrollview and its sub view.

Constraints for scrollview : Top, Trailing, Bottom, Leading and equal width to superview

Constraints for view(inside scrollview) : Top, Trailing, Bottom, Leading, equal width to superview and height(whatever you want to set).

After giving these constraints your view will be scrolled.

Answer (score 0):

Set the contentSize property on the ScrollView. It should scroll then.

Comment: is it possible to set the contentSize property from story board? or do I have to do it from the code?

Comment: I doubt that. You can set the contentSize value on the viewDidLayoutSubviews method.

Answer (score 0):

it may be of AutoLayout problem. if you want to scroll up-down the view then make centre horizontal layout. and make proper auto layout.

self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(self.view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height);

Answer (score 0):

deselect the safe area zone in the properties tab

Answer (score -3):

Set the height of Scroll View more than Screen height.Then it should be work

Comment: Setting height of scrollview scrollview's content is not going to scroll.