# How to get app to scroll when using ScrollView

Tags: swift, xcode

Just a simple question. I'm trying to use a ScrollView and I put a View container inside of the ScrollView in XCode 11 but in the test, the app isn't scrolling. Could someone tell me why this is happening?

[image]

Comment: What is the content of the view? If it is smaller than the scroll view, it will no scroll.

Comment: it should be the same size since I constrained the view to the scrollview

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I put the UIView inside a scrollview in my iOS app and it does not scroll. What am I doing wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36978375/i-put-the-uiview-inside-a-scrollview-in-my-ios-app-and-it-does-not-scroll-what)

Answer (score 0):

According to the pic my guess is that your scroll view is not getting a specific height of your container to scroll.